# Has time lag been calculated?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Books says time lag in which an electron leave atom, in photoelectric effect, is negligible.
Is this negligible value been calculated?

Comment: Which book ? Is it NCERT physics class12 textbook?

Comment: It is given that it's about 10^-9 sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/06/100624144109.htm "Physicists have discovered a time delay when using light pulses to emit electrons from atoms. Until now, it has been assumed that the electrons start moving out of the atom immediately after the impact of the photons. This delay is the shortest time interval measured to date."

Comment: "small but measurable time delay of about twenty attoseconds. "One attosecond is one billionth of one billionth of a second,"..." (Note, "delay".)

Comment: The OP asked whether the delay has been calculated, not whether it has been measured. If it has been measured, we know it is real. But a measurement result doesn't tell us the first thing about how to calculate something.

Comment: @Timaeus I understand what you're saying, and agree; I'm not certain that's what the OP meant (the question is too terse to tell). I assumed they (the OP) understood it the value was known (as per a book), but was not clear if it had been observed. Either would actually require "calculation" (as in 'rithmetic).